# No such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@label='Sales Matrix']"}

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, button, xpath

I've been struggling with this for a while. I have a button like this.

It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I'm confused.

I want to click on this:

[image]

It contains this info:

```
<strong data-bind="css: {'admin__collapsible-title': collapsible,
                      title: !collapsible,
                      '_changed': changed,
                      '_loading': loading,
                      '_error': error}" class="admin__collapsible-title">
            <span data-bind="i18n: label">Sales Matrix</span>
            <!-- ko if: collapsible --><span class="admin__page-nav-item-messages">
                <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message _changed">
                    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-icon"></span>
                    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-tooltip" data-bind="i18n: 'Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved.'">Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved.</span>
                </span>
                <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message _error">
                    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-icon"></span>
                    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-tooltip" data-bind="i18n: 'This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.'">This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.</span>
                </span>
                <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-loader">
                    <span class="spinner">
                       <!-- ko repeat: 8 --><span data-repeat-index="0"></span><span data-repeat-index="1"></span><span data-repeat-index="2"></span><span data-repeat-index="3"></span><span data-repeat-index="4"></span><span data-repeat-index="5"></span><span data-repeat-index="6"></span><span data-repeat-index="7"></span><!-- /ko -->
                    </span>
               </span>
            </span><!-- /ko -->
        </strong>
```

The XPATH is:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/strong
```

I have tried many ways to click on that button but nothing seems to be working for me.

I tried:

```
a) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sales Matrix')]")).click();. 


b) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Sales Matrix']")).click();.

c) WebElement drf=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@label='Sales Matrix']"));
Thread.sleep(1000);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", drf);
```

I even use the JAVASCRIPTEXECUTOR technique but the behaviour is strange.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing a delay. Element should be clicked only when it is clickable.
The best way to do that is to use `WebDriverWait`.
Please try this:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Sales Matrix')]"))).click();
```

Comment: I'm checking this out, pal

Comment: It says: Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebElement

Comment: WebElement element = wait8678.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Sales Matrix')]"))).click(); it says Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebElement

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. No need to keep the left side since we perform the click instantly. See my updated answer

Comment: I did this:  WebDriverWait wait545 = WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));; 
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Sales Matrix')]"))).click();

It says: The method WebDriverWait(WebDriver, Duration) is undefined for the type

Comment: This is not what I wrote... Just `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);` if you working with Selenium 3

Comment: But if i use that i got this error: The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, int) is undefined

Comment: i used this instead:  WebDriverWait wait765 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
 wait765.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Sales Matrix')]"))).click();

Comment: It is strange because i am running the same code and at first execution it works: WebDriverWait wait765 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30)); wait765.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Sales Matrix')]"))).click() and at the second it throws Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //span[contains(.,'Sales Matrix')] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: I mean, that line of code worked for me but it sometimes work and sometimes no

Comment: I clicked now, i added more time:  WebDriverWait wait765 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(200));
 wait765.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Sales Matrix')]"))).click(); 200 this time

Comment: We need to debug this. I can't guess what is going there.

Comment: Take a look at this, pal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73978483/is-not-clickable-at-point-44-230-selenium-strange-behaviour-while-trying-to

Comment: Tried to answer there too

Answer (score 1):

If there's a `span` ancestor above the `strong` element, it might throw off your click. Try this selector:

`"//strong//span[contains(., 'Sales Matrix')]"`

```py
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong//span[contains(., 'Sales Matrix')]")).click();
```

And if that wasn't the case, you probably need to wait longer before finding the element. That's where `WebDriverWait` comes into play.

Comment: Hey pal, i'm checking this out!

Comment: WebElement element = wait8678.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Sales Matrix')]"))).click(); it says Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebElement

Comment: What was the issue with ``driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong//span[contains(., 'Sales Matrix')]")).click();``? The line you ran was not the one I gave you.

Comment: It run well but it did not click anything and same error message: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Can't see the full HTML, so if there's an iframe on that page, you would need to switch into it first. There's a lot of guesswork without knowing all the details.

Comment: How would i switch into it?

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/ has the details. First something like this: ``iframe = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe"));`` then this: ``driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);``

Comment: Is there any way to avoid switching?

Comment: If the element you want to interact with is in an iframe, you need to switch into the iframe first before interacting with the element inside.

Comment: Is there any way that i could share with you the html? I'm kinda lost, don't know what's going on but it is not working

Comment: Not necessary to share the whole HTML. Just look at the full html parent tag path from the ``<body>`` tag all the way to the ``<strong>`` tag. Is there an ``<iframe>`` tag along the way?

Comment: No, there's nothing about "iframe" at all. It is strange because i am running the same code and at first execution it works: WebDriverWait wait765 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30)); wait765.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Sales Matrix')]"))).click() and at the second it throws Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //span[contains(.,'Sales Matrix')] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: I think you're mixing solutions. The selector I gave you was ``"//strong//span[contains(., 'Sales Matrix')]"`` in case there was another ``span`` tag above the ``strong`` tag. Otherwise you're picking a much bigger element that contains a lot of smaller elements.