# is not clickable at point (44, 230) - Selenium strange behaviour while trying to click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This is the error:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click
> intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (44, 230). Other
> element would receive the click: ...

I got these 2 buttons (CATALOG and PRODUCTS):

[image]

CATALOG has this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="_active"><span>Catalog</span></a>
```

XPATH:

```
//*[@id="menu-catalog-catalog"]/a
```

---

PRODUCTS button has this:

<a `href="https://testing.testing/backend/catalog/product/index/key/c3b3205a4808f24f54ac05c10ee0035f5497b72e83f5a6617efe18bbdb9353be/" class=""><span>Products</span></a>`

and this XPATH:

```
//*[@id="menu-catalog-catalog"]/div/ul/li/div/ul/li[1]/a
```

I did this in both cases:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-catalog-catalog\"]/a")).click();


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-catalog-catalog\"]/div/ul/li/div/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
```

The problem is that sometimes it clicks on the buttons and sometimes don't so i dont know what's going on.

---

A new button:

```
<button class="action-submit" type="button" data-bind="click: apply.bind($data, false)">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Search'">Search</span>
    </button>
```

It's XPATH:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button
```

---

**Take a look at this:**

[image]

The SEARCH ICON has this:

```
<button class="action-submit" type="button" data-bind="click: apply.bind($data, false)">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Search'">Search</span>
    </button>
```

XPATH:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button
```

And then, i click on the grid and it has this:

```
<td data-bind="css: getFieldClass($row()), click: getFieldHandler($row()), template: getBody()">
<div class="data-grid-cell-content white-space-preserved" data-bind="html: $col.getLabel($row())">HISENSE 32"</div>
</td>
```

And XPATH:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]
```

I did this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[7]")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use webdriverwait() and wait for element to be clickable.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10)); 
WebElement elementCat = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[.//span[text()='Catalog']]")));
elementCat.click();
WebElement elementProd = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[.//span[text()='Products']]")));
elementProd.click();
```

---

If you are still getting similar error you might need to use `action class` or inject `javascripts` executor.

Comment: Hey pal, i'm checking this out

Comment: Take a look, pal. I have edited my question. What would it be the right way to click on that button?

Comment: No use the way I have suggested. Absolute xpath is fragile should avoid.

Comment: How would you invoke it?

Comment: I am away now. Can reply you back in an hour. Sorry pal.

Answer (score 1):

In case even after using `WebDriverWait` `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` you getting `Element ... is not clickable at point` error I'd suggest clicking that element with JavaScript.
Normally this approach is not recommended, but if no better way this powerful tool can be used.
Trying to improve Kunduk's answer.
So, please try this:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10));   
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement elementCat = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[.//span[text()='Catalog']]")));  
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementCat);
WebElement elementProd = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[.//span[text()='Products']]")));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementProd);
```

Comment: Take a look, pal. I have edited my questions with 2 scenarios: click on search button and click on the grid. How would you do it. What would it? be the right way to do it?

Comment: Take a look, i have added an gif

Comment: I will not have access to computer for 2 days...